# How do I set HTTP response codes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I am trying to create an application in F# that returns a User object, or an error code. Right now they are both being returned with a status code of 200. How would I send the errors with a 400 code instead?

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

[<ApiController>]
[<Route("[controller]")>]
type SelectVacuumController (logger : ILogger<SelectVacuumController>) =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    // Entry point: Get User
    [<HttpGet>]
    member this.Get() =
        try 
            
            let user = getUser()
            user

        with 
            // Return errors if raised
            | MatchFailureException(errorString, i, j) -> errorString // TODO: set response code 400
```

I have tried adding

```
    [<ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)>]
    [<ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)>]
```

and using `IActionResult` but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would maybe try the `BadRequest()` type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Or maybe `StatusCode(code, msg)` for more fine-grained ones?

Comment: I have not tried this, but could you set `Response.StatusCode <- 400`?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! What ended up working was returning ```OkObjectResult(user)``` & ```BadRequestObjectResult(errorString)```